# Why is Dropdown Menu in Webpage Hidden

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select

I've been looking at [this](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/Catalog/?PC_Z7_RJH9U5230O73D0ISNF9B3C3SI1000000_nid=RFCNF5FK7WitWK7G49LP38glNZJXPCDXLDbl) web page and been trying to access the dropdown menus using selenium in python. Here's what I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

url = 'http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Interconnect/Home/Products/ProductCatalog/Catalog/?PC_Z7_RJH9U5230O73D0ISNF9B3C3SI1000000_nid=RFCNF5FK7WitWK7G49LP38glNZJXPCDXLDbl&partNumber=2302-5111-TB'

element_xpath = '//*[@id="Component1"]'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
# wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
print element.is_displayed()
#element_xpath = '/option[@value="02"]'
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print option.get_attribute('value'), option.is_displayed()
# wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath))
# source = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
driver.quit()
```

I don't know why nothing I'm asking for is visible (i.e. `x.is_displayed() == True`), when I can clearly see it on the webpage. I've tried this with Firefox as well.

Odd is the fact that sometimes (like, 5% of the time), the things ARE visible. But 5% isn't really helpful.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The options of the dropdown field only get visible if you click the dropdown selection.
So before you check all_options you should do a click():

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath)
element.click()
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print option.get_attribute('value'), option.is_displayed()
```

It worked in my test but I used `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

Comment: I've actually done this.
The reason I have that first print is to check that I can. Most every time I did that, it would complain that even that wasn't visible, so I couldn't click on the menu.
Are you using the most up-to-date version? Because that might be my problem...

Comment: I have version 2.42.1 by pip install. Btw: Are these commands executed in the shell or runned by a script? If it's a script it might be too fast and you have to wait for the page finish rendering.

Comment: I'm doing it in a script.
I was thinking that could be the case. I have a few lines commented in my code, and I thought that if I uncommented them stuff would wait a little bit, but that didn't help.